# What function is K&R exercise 2-6 really asking for?

Tags: kernighan-and-ritchie

> Exercise 2-6. Write a function setbits(x,p,n,y) that returns x with the n bits that begin at
>   position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged.

I have been trying to mess around with this function on paper for a good hour or two, and I am not getting anywhere.

The way I interpret the function is that a bit field, x, of arbitrary length is to look at it's `n` bits starting `p` places from the right-most bit. Change these `n` bits to the same bits located in the `n` right-most bits in a bit field, y, of arbitrary length.

Example: `p = 7` `n = 9` with x as the top field, y is the middle, the result is the bottom field.

[image]

---

I am having trouble determining how I could do this with arbitrary sized bit fields. Should I use `sizeof(x) * 8` or is this unnecessary?

I would appreciate any hints you can provide to how one can make such a function.

I would also like to know any other interpretations of the exercise, possibly a version that may be easier although I am sure this one can be done. Given how long it is taking me I would appreciate a second opinion on the matter, thanks.

Comment: This question is also throwing me for a loop. I feel like the level of difficulty grew by an order of magnitude between questions 2-5 to 2-6.

Comment: @pdoherty926 - totally agree. I think the assumption of authors that we know bit-shifting is what is making this appear like such a chasm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `x` and `y` are ints, you know that the size of the bit field can be no larger than the number of bits in an int.

Since this is C, assume that the right-most bit is #0, so `p = 0, n = 1` means to replace the right-most bit in `x`.

What you want to do is:

1. create a bitmask -- a number with the right-most `n` bits set to 1 and all the rest 0;
2. bitwise `and` the bitmask with `y` to extract the right-most `n` bits of `y` and shift it left `p` bits;
3. shift the bitmask `p` bits to the left to create a bitmask that will operate on `n` bits starting at position `p`;
4. bitwise `and` the inverse shifted bitmask with `x` to mask out the bits you want to replace;
5. bitwise `or` the result of 2 and 4 to get your answer.

Rollover to see it in code:

> ```
> int bitmask = ~((~0) << n);
> return ((bitmask & y) << p) | (~(bitmask << p) & x);
> ```

Comment: Hmm, I thought that the number of bits in `int` is different on some machines, but I could always be wrong of course. By the way, how do we know `x` and `y` are of type `int`?

Comment: Yes, the number of bits in an `int` differs by machine, so you just have to write the code so that it doesn't matter. If a type isn't specified, the default is `int`. I didn't see a type specified so I assumed the default.

Comment: I have been trying your function using the python shell for ease of use, and it does not appear to be working as desired. I also did it by hand and the results are not quite right. By hand I tried `x = 0110 1101` `y = 0110 1001` `p = 4` `n = 3` I am expecting a result of `0100 1101` but I get `0000 1101` with your function.

Comment: Oops, I left out the step of shifting `y` to the left by `p`. I fixed my program, and my code yields `0001 1101` for your example (as I would expect).

Comment: I am still not able to get this to work, have you tested it with 32 bit values? It could be we have a different understanding of the specifications which was fairly ambiguous, I will upload a picture to show what I understand the function to do.

Comment: Based on my definition, your example has `p = 6`, not 7. When I try my updated code with `p = 6, n = 9, x = 3114111148, y = 2931310294`, I get exactly what you show in your picture (a result of `3114101548`).

Comment: Okay that explains it, as suspected. Good work on this I will practice more and make my version of the function, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for this exercise, I've added plenty comments for myself - hope someone will find it useful.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* k&r exercise 2-6 */

int setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y);

int main(void) {
  setbits(218, 3, 3, 170);
}

/*
 * returns x with the n bits that begin at position p
 * set to rightmost n bits of y, leaving other bits
 * unchanged.
 *
 * all comments for setbits(218, 3, 3, 170)
 */
int setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y) {

  // get the mask for y - it is a n long mask.
  unsigned mask = ~0;           // 1111 1111
  mask = mask << n;     // shift n to get 1111 1000
  mask = ~mask;         // flip to get    0000 0111

  // AND y and the mask to 'delete' the bits that are not 1's
  // therefore extracting the desired n bits 
  y = y & mask;  // result 0000 0010 (decimal 2)

  // shift y p bits to the left to place the desired bit pattern where we need it
  // it will not be used until the last step though.
  y = y << p;

  // now we need to reuse the mask we've created earlier. reminder, currently
  // it is 0000 0111. we need to move the 1's to the left to 'aim' at the
  // spot we want to mask in x.
  mask = mask << p;

  // in order to keep the bits we want in x, we need to AND x with the inverted mask
  // inverting the mask:
  mask = ~mask;

  // &'ing x and mask:
  x = x & mask;

  // now finally, to insert the bit pattern we extracted from y, we need to OR
  // x and y.
  
  x = x | y;
  printf("%d\n", x); // expected: 210;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the image with the bitpatterns is a correct interpretation of what the exercise in K&R amounts to. However, the corresponding value `p=7` should be `p=14`. This seems to follow from consistent usage of `p`, when looking at K&R's implementation of `getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n)`, which return `n` bits from `x` starting at position `p`, where 0 is the rightmost position. Quote from K&R: "For example, `getbits(x, 4, 3)` returns the three bits in positions 4, 3, 2, right adjusted."

The algorithm is therefore:

```
int bitmask = ~((~0) << n);
return ((bitmask & y) << (p - n + 1)) | (~(bitmask << (p - n + 1)) & x);
```